# Android AutoCompleteTextView - How to execute requests in parallel to get results for the filter

Tags: android, multithreading, autocompletetextview

As the user types, I need to fire off three requests in parallel to fetch the data for the list that is displayed for AutoCompleteTextView dropdown. I understand that performFiltering is done on a thread. Should this method spawn off 3 more AsyncTasks or threads ? Or is there any other way ?

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) - here one call to web api is done - you can  call your three requests in the same thread or in their own three threads and wait for their completion by using `join` method

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use Asynctasks or Threads.
Simply call 3 requests using **Volley** or **Retrofit**. Those are asynchronous. And maintain 3 boolean variables for 3 requests. Initially values of 3 variables are false. when requests receives the result make relevant variable true and check whether all 3 variables are true. if so all 3 results are came otherwise not. so if all 3 true you can show the results in dropdown. 
If you want user to wait till result coming, display a loading icon or a progressbar and when all 3 requests completed hide that loader